# subversion directory structure diff between revisions

Tags: svn, diff

I can't seem to find a way to use Subversion to take a diff of directory structure changes between two revisions. I'd like to see what files/directories/symlinks have been added/deleted between two revisions. svn diff only seems to show me contents. svn log --verbose can kind of show what I'm looking for, but I have to add up all the changes to get a comprehensive summary. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: not sure why this is marked off topic. any professional system administrator should be committing config files, documentation, scripts, etc. to a repository to keep track of changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `--summarize` flag to `svn diff`:

```
svn diff --summarize -r REV1:REV2 URL_OR_PATH
```